# Function returning dictionary

Tags: python

I have to take a function called `make_square` that takes a tuple in the parameter as a range of numbers (starting point and ending point (inclusive)). The function should return a dictionary with the numbers as keys and its squares as values.
The output should be: `{5: 25, 6: 36, 7: 49, 8: 64, 9: 81}` When I call `make_square((5,9))`

Here's what I tried:

```
dictionary = dict()
for num in (number):
    dictionary[num] = num ** 2
return dictionary 

make_square((5,9))
```

The output came:

```
{5: 25, 9: 81}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `range()`. `for num in (number)` only iterate over the values in tuple so dictionary will contain only 5 and 9.

```
def make_square(numbers):
    d = {}
    for num in range(numbers[0], numbers[1] + 1):
        d[num] = num ** 2
    return d

print(make_square((5,9)))
```

**Output:**

```
{5: 25, 6: 36, 7: 49, 8: 64, 9: 81}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cube the number, not square.

```
 dictionary[num] = num ** 2
```

instead of

```
 dictionary[num] = num ** 3
```

Answer (score 1):

The `**` is the power operation, to get the square, or power of 2, do `**2`. Also I'd suggest you pass 2 argument, `start` and `end` and not a tuple that contains both, for this simple method that is a better choice

```
def make_square(start, end):
    d = {}
    for num in range(start, end + 1):
        d[num] = num ** 2
    return d
```

With dict-comprehension

```
def make_square(start, end):
    return {num: num ** 2 for num in range(start, end + 1)}
```